# Can setup and teardown be called for each of the Test Cases?

Tags: c#, nunit

```
[Setup]
public void RunBeforeAnyTest()
{
}

[TearDown]
public void RunAfterEveryTest()
{
}

[Test]
public void Test1()
{
}

[TestCase("case1")]
[Testcase("case2")]
public void Test2()
{
}
```

In above example, the Setup and TearDown gets executed before and after Test1 and Test2. But I want it to execute before and after individual test case in Test2. Is it possible with nunit framework? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure? I thought the behaviour is like you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2):

After correcting for some typos:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Class1
{
    [SetUp]
    public void RunBeforeAnyTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("RunBeforeAnyTest");
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void RunAfterEveryTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("RunAfterEveryTest");
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test1()");
    }

    [TestCase("case1")]
    [TestCase("case2")]
    public void Test2(string param)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Test2({param})");
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
RunBeforeAnyTest
Test1()
RunAfterEveryTest

RunBeforeAnyTest 
Test2(case1) 
RunAfterEveryTest

RunBeforeAnyTest 
Test2(case2) 
RunAfterEveryTest
```

Isn't that what you hoped?